# sequelize bulkCreate with updateOnDuplicate on all columns

Tags: mariadb, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize to perform a bulkCreate on one of my models. It is basically a simple sync-operation and therefore I want to update the rows that already exist. As per, the `updateOnDuplicate` is described as:

> Fields to update if row key already exists (on duplicate key update)? (only supported by MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite >= 3.24.0 & Postgres >= 9.5). **By default, all fields are updated.**

However, there is no way to perform the default behavior. sequelize expects an array of strings and won't except e.g. a simple `true` for all columns.

So how can i update ALL fields?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am struggling on the same question.

Comment: No unfortunately not

Comment: Facing same issue. Couldn't find a solution yet.